# How find similar records on some conditions in SQL or Linq or Entity Framework

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a table of `request` records.

These requests have various data columns like `RequestId`, `Date`, `Amount`, `PersonId`, etc.

When two records have two days or less difference in date (for example `12/12/2021` and `14/12/2021`) or have `5000` or less difference in `Amount` (for example `545000` and `542000`) and have exactly same `PersonId` - and some other conditions like these - they'll be considered as `similar` or `duplicated` requests.

What I want is a query that gives me all the records and an added column called `similar records` that contains `RequestId` of all similar records.

| RequestId | Amount | Date | PersonId | Similar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100,000 | 10/12/2021 | 63 | 3,5 |
| 2 | 95,000 | 12/12/2021 | 45 | NULL |
| 3 | 43,000 | 12/12/2021 | 63 | 1 |
| 4 | 38,000 | 15/12/2021 | 56 | NULL |
| 5 | 100,000 | 16/12/2021 | 63 | 1 |
| 6 | 63,000 | 25/12/2021 | 45 | NULL |

I'm a .NET framework developer and I'm using Entity Framework and Linq commands.

Note that I know that I can do that with loops, but I want it to be one integrated command to produce such an output. Thanks.

Comment: Can't be done, logically. Suppose you have three amounts, 5000, 10000, and 15000. Which amounts should be deemed "equal"? They all belong in one group with 100000, but 5000 and 15000 can't be in one group.

Comment: for the 5000, similar column will be id of record of 10000
for the 10000, similar column will be id of records of 5000,10000
for the 15000, similar column will be id of records of 10000

Answer (score 0):

I hope EF Core can translate this query correctly:

```cs
var requests = context.Requests.AsQueryable();

var result = requests.Select(r => new 
    {
        r.RequestId,
        r.Amount,
        r.Date,
        r.PersonId,
        Similar = requests
            .Where(o => o.PersonId == r.PersonId && o.RequestId != r.RequestId)
            .Where(o => Math.Asbs(EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(o.Date, r.Date)) <= 2 
                || Math.Asbs(o.Amount, r.Amount)) <= 5000
            )
            .Select(o => o.RequestId)
            .ToArray()
    })
    .ToList();
```